# Add .ics attachments in Inbox by Gmail to Google Calendar

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, inbox-by-gmail

I'm using Google Inbox with Google Apps for Work and unfortunately the .ics attachments sent by meetup.com are not added to my calender. But when I switch to Gmail then there is a button to add the Appointment to my calendar.

Is there a way to get the same behavior in Google Inbox?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this thread on Google Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/RuRRTr8gDgc), this is a known limitation and they have it on the slate for future implementation. I expect that the more people tell Google they want this, the more likely Google will implement it and sooner.

**EDIT**

I've noticed that Google Inbox has started automatically adding events to your Calendar when you accept the invitation. This isn't identical to the functionality you're requesting, but it addresses most cases.

Answer (score 4):

This is not always convenient, but if you use the Google Inbox application on Android there is an option to add events to your google Calendar. I generally get my phone out and add events from there.

Comment: You can open .ics files with the Android Google Calendar app, and add them.